# How to globally change the language in Blazor Server during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a problem with my blazor server web application, where I want to implement localization but I have problems with it.
In My Program.cs I have set the following:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
app.UseRequestLocalization("en");
```

In the _Host.cshtml the code checks the LiteDB database if everything is set. If it isn't then it displays the Setup.razor component before the App.razor component. In the Setup.razor component I launch another component called LanguageSetup.razor, where I want the admin to set a global language for the app.

In the component there is a `select` with languages listed and bellow a button (like wordpress) with text continue in correct language which must be displayed immediately after selecting a language.

Now this part works, it successfully changes the text to the correct one with the following code:

```
string selectedLanguage = args.Value.ToString();
var culture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

But when I try to click the button the **text goes back to english**. And when I try to refresh the page the language isn't saved. How can I fix this? After this I will save the language code to LiteDB database and read the language in _Host and apply it to every page.

Comment: can [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference-1) help you?